# Is it normal my phone heat becomes unbearable?

Tags: lumia-925

I have my Lumia 925 for about a week now. It gets unbearably heated up above the camera when constant gaming. I have to close the game to let it cool for a bit. 
Is this a normal behavior?
If it is, does constant heat affect my battery life/cellphone?

Comment: It is heating up while gaming pretty much for me too (I wouldn't say unbearable, but yeah, it's damn hot). But not sure whether this is normal (I guess it is) and how this affects battery...

Comment: So you are playing Asphalt 8 too? Hahaha. Mine 920 heats a lot too. Sometimes I think is related to cellular data. Heats a lot in this case too.

Comment: @VitorCanova Pylon mostly, and when I play game that has high graphics demands and requires Internet connection, it heats up faster. So it's rather annoying!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sadly it does sound normal for the [925](http://www.notebookcheck.net/Review-Nokia-Lumia-925-Smartphone.99788.0.html#c1249021) and a lot of other devices when playing games:

> As expected, these values increase under full load, up to 47.0 °C in
>   the case of our test device. Thus, the Lumia 925 gets rather hot

If it is actually physically painful to touch the device, then it might be worth trying to exchange it for another one or a different model.

I would speculate that it would have a negative affect on the phone if it was overheating for extreme periods a day, day in, day out. But I personally wouldn't worry about it during standard use.

Answer (score 1):

Yes! It is! 
All devices that has a processor may become hot when you are playing games or when you browse internet for a long time. 
It has a built-in anti-heat damage system so you don't have to worry about the temperature...it will freeze again in 2-3 minutes if you end up playing games or if you leave it for some minutes.

Your battery may not be affected by this, but would be better to be carefull. It could be verry dangerous for your Skin. I wouldn't recommend a long exposition...

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is common for Lumia 925 (in case for most of the devices) while in Lumia 925 it happens very frequently but after reaching a particular temperature it seems constant. If its not your case then better get it exchanged but before that I would suggest following things:

- Turn off your WIFI or Internet connection if not required.
- Turn off other apps which you are not using at that moment as you are playing game.
- Check for proper case/cover for your phone, as sometimes these cause the problem (not completely but up to an extent)

Answer (score -2):

change the brightness setting to medium and it will be ok

Comment: I don't think the brighness is the problem here as the heat comes from the processor.