# Is it normal for my phone to heatup?

Tags: lumia

I bought Microsoft Lumia 640. It is heating from the right side of the back beside the sound button. It is generating heat even when browsing and playing music. The heat is not unbearable but noticeable. Is it normal or should I exchange. Please help

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/3770/106

Comment: Please search before asking a question!